# Select distinct statement not working, Active reports and SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a relatively unique problem, and although I have looked for 2 days I cant find a correct answer yet.

In my current project I am using active reports 6 to create reports out of data stored on our SQL server.

I am attempting to use a select distinct statement with no luck.

I am using SQL to create a view, however I am  not saving that as a view, the code itself will be run as a query everytime the report is requested.

The report will show all the current vehicles the company has on lease. So the report must only bring back unique hits on the registration field. As it can be in there multiple times, If more than 1 person has driven that vehicle etc..

Here is my sql code

```
select distinct on Registration from CompanyCars

CompanyCars.Registration as Regno,
[Staff Details].[first Name] + ' ' + [Staff Details].[Last Name] as Driver,
CompanyCars.Car_Type as VehicleType,    
CompanyCars.Reg_Date as Regdate,
CompanyCars.Price as Price,


[Staff Details].[NI Number] as NInumber,

CompanyCars.End_Mile - CompanyCars.Start_Mile as UsedMiles,
CompanyCars.Lease_Mile -(CompanyCars.End_Mile - CompanyCars.Start_Mile) as ExcessMiles,
case when CompanyCars.Lease_Mile -(CompanyCars.End_Mile - CompanyCars.Start_Mile) < 0 and CompanyCars.Excess <> 0 then (CompanyCars.End_Mile - CompanyCars.Start_Mile)- CompanyCars.Lease_Mile * (CompanyCars.Excess / 100) else 0 end as overunder,
CompanyCars.Excess as ExcessRate,
CompanyCars.Company as Company



FROM [Staff Details] INNER JOIN [CompanyCarHistory] ON [Staff Details].Staffref = [CompanyCarHistory].StaffRef
 INNER JOIN CompanyCars ON CompanyCars.Registration = [CompanyCarHistory].Registration
```

Any Ideas anyone? My SQL isn't great.

Paul

Comment: What RDBMS? SQL Server?

Comment: so what output do you expect and what output do you get?

Comment: I expect to get a list of all our current vehicles and who is driving them now, the best I have got so far is a list of all our vehicles, but listed multiple times with everyone who has driven them previoulsy.

Comment: And we are using SQL server 2012

Comment: why we need on here "distinct on Registration"?

Comment: I dont know.. I want a it to pick unique fields based on the registration. I cant get it to work, so thats why im asking.

Comment: Shouldn't be first row something like "select distinct " instead of "select distinct on Registration from CompanyCars" ?

Comment: I tried that, but it still returns the same car multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put yours code into subselect (not tested):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyCars.Registration ORDER BY CompanyCars.Reg_Date DESC) AS rowid
    CompanyCars.Registration as Regno,
    [Staff Details].[first Name] + ' ' + [Staff Details].[Last Name] as Driver,
    CompanyCars.Car_Type as VehicleType,    
    CompanyCars.Reg_Date as Regdate,
    CompanyCars.Price as Price,


    [Staff Details].[NI Number] as NInumber,

    CompanyCars.End_Mile - CompanyCars.Start_Mile as UsedMiles,
    CompanyCars.Lease_Mile -(CompanyCars.End_Mile - CompanyCars.Start_Mile) as ExcessMiles,
    case when CompanyCars.Lease_Mile -(CompanyCars.End_Mile - CompanyCars.Start_Mile) < 0 and CompanyCars.Excess <> 0 then (CompanyCars.End_Mile - CompanyCars.Start_Mile)- CompanyCars.Lease_Mile * (CompanyCars.Excess / 100) else 0 end as overunder,
    CompanyCars.Excess as ExcessRate,
    CompanyCars.Company as Company




    FROM [Staff Details] INNER JOIN [CompanyCarHistory] ON [Staff Details].Staffref = [CompanyCarHistory].StaffRef
     INNER JOIN CompanyCars ON CompanyCars.Registration = [CompanyCarHistory].Registration
) as Temp
where rowid = 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate! Thats perfecto!